# How to save JSON response into an array

Tags: c#, blazor

I have three URLs that I loop through and try to fetch result from.
The URLs are basic, like:

```
http://foo.bar/id/2563
http://foo.bar/id/1453
http://foo.bar/id/7321
```

My foreach looks something like this:

```
foreach (var url in urls){
  HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

  body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(body);
}
```

Here is the thing, each JSON has

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: John,
    Address: {
      zipcode: '',
      town: ''
    }
}]
```

The idea for me is to display all `Address.zipcode` and `Address.town` of each JSON.

For some reason though my web page displays only the data from the first url, and **not from the second and third urls**

This is my model:

```
public class JsonData {
 public int id { get; set; }
 public string name { get; set; }
 public Dictionary<string, string> Address{ get; set; }
}
```

This is just a code I wrote, because the code is fine but I don't know why I am only seeing one zipcode and one town out of many.

It seems like in the foreach loop, only one data is saved `result` whereas I am trying to save all of them.

My HTML is basic and looks like this:

```
@foreach(var item in result) {
  <p> @item.Address.zipcode - <small>@item.Address.town</small> <p>
}
```

Comment: We don't have the part where you add `result` in your list of `JsonData`: It should be inside the `foreach`.

Comment: Where's your collection of `JsonData` and how are you populating it?  Your first  block of code shows a loop and getting of `result` but not what you're doing with it.   Does the collection `JsonData` shown in the last block contain three rows?   Calling your collection by the same name as your data class is pretty confusing!  You need to show much more code for anything but a wild guess at where your problem lies.

Comment: You might be facing a deadlock, since for some reason you are using `.Result` instead of awaiting:  `client.GetAsync(url).Result` should be `await client.GetAsync(url);`.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Sorry, updated

Comment: You are still just overwriting `result` upon each iteration instead of adding it to some list.,

Comment: @KirkWoll I think that is the problem. I thought it might be too, but I once did the same exact thing and it worked. Can you please answer on how to handle this problem?  I am sure you know the problem

Comment: Is this really the code you are using? I don't see how it would compile if `result` is of the same type in your two pieces of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't actually get what you are asking for because lack of information. But you can push deserialized "results" into an array.

```
//Create an empty array of type JsonData
JsonData[] results = Array.Empty<JsonData>();

foreach (var url in urls)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
    //Push each deserialized response into the results array
    Array.Resize(ref results, results.Length + 1);
    results[results.GetUpperBound(0)] = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonData>(body);
}
```

Then you can iterate over the results array.